# How is asynchronous programming implemented under the hood without continuous cheching?

Tags: asynchronous, operating-system, implementation, low-level

I'm currently exploring asynchronous programming.
While I understand the basics of how this works conceptually, I'm interested in a deeper understanding of its implementation.
How is asynchronous programming implemented without resorting to busy waiting? For instance, **is the kernel responsible for notifying the runtime by periodically checking a flag indicating data availability from the network adapter**(example for asynchronous database call), or are there more efficient mechanisms involved? I'm interested in understanding the technical details of **how this process avoids continuous checking** for data availability while still ensuring timely execution of asynchronous methods.